# Can't input string into a struct array

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct

I have a program that has people input info into an array of structs. The info includes a City name, a Day number, and a Fahrenheit temperature. For some reason it skips the part where you input the City name.

```
void input_TempInfo(struct TempInfo * arr, int size)
{
    int i, k;

    for (i = 0, k = 0; k < size; i++, k++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter the city: ");
        while (getchar() != '\n')        << **Edit**
            ;
        while (((arr[k].city[i] = getchar()) != '\n') && (i < MAXCHARS))
            i++;
        arr[k].city[i] = '\0';

        do
        {
            printf("\nEnter the day: ");
            scanf("%i", &arr[k].day);
            if (arr[k].day < 1 || arr[k].day > 366)
            {
                printf("\nInvalid day number. Type another: ");
                scanf("%i", &arr[k].day);
            }
        } while (arr[k].day < 1 || arr[k].day > 366);

        printf("Enter a temperature in Fahrenheit: ");
        scanf("%lf", &arr[k].fahr);

        arr[k].cels = (arr[k].fahr - 32) * 5/9;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading the City name, instead of using `getchar()` , use `scanf` 
Change the below code from

```
    printf("\nEnter the city: ");
    while (getchar() != '\n')        << **Edit**
        ;
    while (((arr[k].city[i] = getchar()) != '\n') && (i < MAXCHARS))
        i++;
    arr[k].city[i] = '\0';
```

to

```
    printf("Enter the city: \n");
    scanf("%s", &arr[k].city);
```

or //without using scanf

```
    char c;
    while (((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (i < MAXCHARS -1)) { //Because the last character would be '\0' (NULL).
        arr[k].city[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    arr[k].city[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: @JordanLindsay : updated answer without using `scanf`

Answer (score 0):

When you use scanf(), newline characters are being left in the stdin. Scanf() has no problems consuming newlines, but your getchar() loop ends immediately `getchar()) != '\n'`.

You could check if the first char is a newline and consume it before reading with getchar().

Comment: By consume it do you mean use a 'while' loop? Like 'while (getchar() != '\n')   ;'

Comment: I used a while loop to clear the keyboard buffer before I input the city names, but any city name after the first is being messed up.